# `friendly_id` doesn't allow delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, crud, friendly-id

I'm using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to make my URL's more user friendly, but since implementing the gem, my `destroy` action just goes to the `show` action.  I'm currently using:

```
= link_to 'Delete', entry_path(e), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Really really?'
```

and have also tried:

```
= link_to 'Delete', entry_path(e.id), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Really really?'
```

The first gets routed to the `show` action of `entries_controller` and the second only gives me this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"entries", :id=>nil}
```

If anyone else has been using `friendly_id`, how did you take care of the `Destroy` action?

Comment: try exchanging `entry_path(e)` with just the object `e`

Comment: what is the "e" object? Is this in a block?

Comment: Yes, the block is `@entries.each do |e|`

Comment: Swapping out `entry_path(e)` with just the object `e` didn't work, thanks for the suggestion though @pduersteler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you integrated an ujs (e.g `jquery-rails` or `jquery-ujs`) js lib into the page? Because `:method => :delete` creates a `data-method` attribute and its click is then processed by the unobtrusive rails js library. If the link is not processed, it is either a simple show or a simple edit link instead of a link to the actual delete method.

Comment: I do have `jquery-rails`, this is a 3.2.5 app so it's included.  I'll be sure to check on that.  Thanks for insight too :)